# QT: How to set resizeEvent for widget without overriding the widget class

Tags: qt, resize

I have a labels with images added through the designer, and I want to handle their resize event. So I want a specific function to be called once they are resized.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install an event filter to the labels.

For more details you can see the Qt documentation about [Event filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Example:

```
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   ui.setupUi(this);
   theLabel->installEventFilter(this);
} 

bool MainWidget::eventFilter(QObject* o, QEvent* e)
{
    if(e->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        //manage the resize event
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It says Object is not declared, how to include it?

Comment: Sorry, is QObject, not Object. I've edited the answer